# Stepping through PHP changes MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql

Under plain PHP 5.3, I have some code which uses MySQL to first deletes some old records, record a log, perform a few tiny operations and then adds new replacement records.

The delete command looks like this:

```
DELETE FROM `rtable` WHERE `UserName`='%s';
```

And the add commands looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`UserName`,`Attribute`,`op`,`Value`) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s');
```

Oddly though, the insert commands appear to not execute when running normally, however if I enable my debugger and step through one line at a time, it appears to work. Likewise, if I insert a sleep command of two seconds after the delete commands. It appears to work. I am therefor assuming that the insert commands are running -before- the delete commands and thus the delete commands are also erasing the new records.

How can I get PHP to wait for the delete operation to finish before continuing to the insert commands?

Comment: You could pop a transaction around the delete query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds really odd. 
Do you happen to have a replicated database cluster?
Also, do you check the return value of the mysql_query or whatever command and print the error message (which of course is not recommended for scripts in production)?

Comment: Turns out it was a replication issue between our rather simple Master writing, slave for reading layout. So the delete was erasing the new records after they had been inserted later on in the PHP. Forcing the system just to use the master server fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am not totally certain how PHP deals with processes and how consecutive queries are run, but if you want to make certain to encapsulate the delete in a transaction, you can do so with PDO like this:

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();
$sth = $dbh->exec("DELETE FROM `rtable` WHERE `UserName`='%s'");
$dbh->commit();
// You could also pop a transaction around the inserts 
// in case another page tries to do the same
$sth = $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO `table` 
    (`UserName`,`Attribute`,`op`,`Value`) 
    VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s')");
```

BTW: I took the liberty of correcting the single quotes to backticks in your queries.

Comment: The current code is legacy so we can't use PDO. However I tried standard transaction SQL commands appear to have no effect.

Comment: @Nidonocu Did you change the single quotes to back-ticks in the old queries? That might also be causing issues.

Comment: I only changed it for SO, it uses backticks in the real code.